# Difference of the frames

Tags: kinect, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I work with the ar_kinect package to recognize the ARMarkers with the kinect. So, there are different frames, but I don't really know the difference, because I work with it the first time.

So maybe someone can explain me the different from the frames: Thats the view_frames Result:

/Test_Pattern <-- /camera_rgb_optical_frame(Broadcaster: ar_kinect) <-- /camera_rgb_frame(Broadcaster:/camera_base_link3) <-- /camera_link(Broadcaster:/camera_base_link1) --> /camera_depth_frame(Broadcaster:camera_base_link) --> /camera_depth_optical_frame(Broadcaster:/camera_base_link2)

The Test_Pattern should be the ARMarker.
Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56829/difference-of-the-frames/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These frames represent multiple frames that are associated with kinect.They are defined in kinect_frames.launch that comes with openni_launch package. camera_rgb_optical_frame is header_frame_id for images that is capturing pattern. Hence pattern is defined in that frame.

These frames also define static transformation between stereo cameras, IR projector,  position of  kinect w.r.t.to camera_links.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on 2013-03-03**:
Ok, thank you! I looked at the kinect_frames.launch. Can you or somebody explain me for what stands the six numbers after args in the launch file? I think the first three are some coordinates and the last three angle?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-03-03**:
The first three are position coordinates in x,y,z and next three are orientation along x,y,z ....